# Eclipse wont display line of class

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am trying to debug an application which is using BouncyCastle to decrypt data from a file.

While decrypting the code throws a PGPException and I am now trying to debug the code. As I am digging in to the code of javax.crypto.Cipher Eclipse isnt able to show me the current line which is about to be executed. It says the current line is around 1800 - but it won't it show me. In the Perspective the Class ends at 1513 so everything beyond that seems to be there but isnt displayed to me.

I am using OpenJDK8 and it's corresponding Sourcefiles from the Ubuntu Install-repository.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You're probably looking at the decompiled class file which is missing comments etc, making it significantly shorter. Eclipse should still know what line is being executed, but it probably won't line up with the line number in the stack trace. Download the sources if you want an exact match.

Comment: I think it's common best practice *not* to use any installed JDK for development but to use a separate JDK (f.e. from https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html#x64_linux). That way you don't rely on any OS package updates or the lack of them and always use a fixed JDK for your developement.